# Minecraft Unbreakable

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do you use the Roughly Enough Items cheat command method? Because I want to edit the NBT.

So if I click on an item, it will have the `Unbreakable` tag. I searched the whole night just for this and couldn't find an answer. Or is there a command that modifies the main hand item to have the `Unbreakable` tag?

Or is there a Fabric mod that allows me to automatically changes the main hand item/held item to become unbreakable? (In survival mode, require OP access)

Comment: Sorry, i didn't realize. It was a midnight when i posted

Answer (score -2):

Well if your looking to automatically enchant the weapon/armor/tool you are holding, get a command block and put in

> Enchant @username unbreaking 3

And set it to repeat, unconditional, always active. Then you can type in

> /Gamerule commandblockfeedback false

However it does require cheats. Hope that helps!

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't what the OP asked for - they specifically wanted to know how to edit an item's NBT data to add the Unbreakable tag, not how to apply the Unbreaking _enchantment_, which isn't the same thing